# How to fetch mongo db records having BigDecimal value greater than a value using java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am unable to fetch mongo db records having amount (`bigdecimal` value) greater than 0 using following in java.

```
    Query query=new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("amount").gt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

- It looks like first you have to convert the existing documents mongodb to store it as `Decimal128`

```
   db.xxx.find({ }) 
  .forEach( function (x) { 
    x.price = new NumberDecimal(x.amount); 
    db.xxx.save(x); 
  });
```

- Then you need to write a `Converter`

```
    @Bean
    CustomConversions customConverions() {
     Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal> decimal128ToBigDecimal 
                    = new Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public BigDecimal convert(Decimal128 s) {
            return s==null ? null : s.bigDecimalValue();
        }
      };

      Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128> bigDecimalToDecimal128 
                    = new Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128>() {
        @Override
        public Decimal128 convert(BigDecimal s) {
            return s==null ? null : new Decimal128(s);
        }
      };

      return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(decimal128ToBigDecimal, 
                                 bigDecimalToDecimal128));
    }
```

Comment: I can not change datatype of existing field. It will always be BigDecimal in documents. Please suggest a way so I can fetch results without modification in existing db.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't able to compare it in mongo while it is stored as string